# control unit cpu mips

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu, mips32

When I have an address in the program counter how is it read ?
i have understand this:
When there is an address in the Program Counter (PC), the Control Unit (CU) reads the contents of the PC by sending an address signal over the address bus to access the main memory and retrieve the corresponding instruction. This happens at every clock cycle.

1)So the address signal contains the same address contained in the Program Counter ?
2)How does the control unit know which address to transmit in the address signal to access the memory
In practice, how is the content of the program counter read? and what logic circuit are implemented?

I am Studying mips cpu

Comment: 1) Yes 2) The program counter is a register, and a register is a form of memory. Memory typically has a signal that enables its output. The output is wired to the bus.

Comment: This is a CPU hardware design question, not a computer programming question.

Comment: There is no there's no decision to make: the address to read from instruction memory for instruction fetch is the value held by the PC.  The processor does have choices in how to alter the next PC (to alter the PC for the next cycle), which depends on the instruction executing, but once the PC is updated, the processor simple uses it with no further consideration.